# Bash typed ahead Enter appearing as Tab

Tags: bash, command-line

When I type the below, `ech` does not execute. Instead, the typed-ahead <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is turned into a <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```bash
$ sleep 5[Enter]
ech[Enter]
$ ech
echkpnt          echkpnt.default  echkpnt.fluent   echkpnt.ls_dyna  echo
$ ech<cursor-is-here>
```

I checked with a co-worker and he doesn't have this problem, so I believe it's solvable. I have played around with a lot of stty settings. No luck. I know this has something to do with "cooked" editing mode, but I can't find the fix.

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 44; columns 127; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint ignpar -parmrk -inpck istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Edit: I captured a raw character log using KiTTY. I think I am on the trail now. It appears to be an interaction with my PS1 prompt coloring. That would explain why my co-worker is not seeing it. I'll post an answer when I figure it out.

---

[image: KiTTY log]

---

Edit2: Here is my PS1.

```bash
        reset="\[$(tput setaf 0)\]"
        red="\[$(tput setaf 9)\]"
        green="\[$(tput setaf 10)\]"
        yellow="\[$(tput setaf 11)\]"
        white="\[$(tput setaf 15)\]"
        PS1="${green}\$ ${white}"
```

Comment: What's in your `bind -P`?

Comment: @l0b0 Found it. Thanks for the help! Your comments actually made me dig deeper!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the bash `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable was being set by some (still not found) system/project file that was being sourced. My work environment has a very difficult to follow tree of sourced files. So, even though I was setting my own `PS1`, the commands in `PROMPT_COMMAND` were still being executed. The solution is to unset this variable as part of my user bashrc file.

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
printf "\033k%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/\~}"
```

[Explanation of PROMPT_COMMAND](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).